# Laravel validation with exist function

Tags: validation, laravel-5

I have laravel change password code, with fields: oldpassword, newpasword, confirmedpassword
Now to validate the form the newpasword must be the same as confirmedpassword, and the old must be existed for this user in database

this is my view code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="oldpsw">your current password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="oldpsw" 
placeholder="your current password" name="oldpsw">
@if ($errors->has('oldpsw'))
<span class="help-block">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('oldpsw') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<label for="password">new password</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="new 
password" name="password" required>
@if ($errors->has('password'))
<span class="help-block">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password_confirmation">Password Confirmation</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_confirmation" 
placeholder="Password Confirmation"  name="password_confirmation" required>
</div>
```

my controller:

> ```
> return Validator::make($data, ['oldpsw' =>   'required|string','password' =>   'required|string|confirmed','password_confirmation' => 'required|string',
>   'password' =>Rule::exists('accounts')->where(function ($query) { $query->where('student_no', Auth::user()->student_no);}), ]);
> ```

If I want to use |confirmed my field must be as the name of model fillable field, but if I want to check the db existence it requires the field also as the same column in db.
My Db column is:password, what can I do to solve this problem

Edit: I mean for the two cases both fields must to be named: password  !

Comment: No, answers yet..
can anyone help?

Comment: You're code isn't formatted, your controller code is just 1 line of code, probably why no one has replied. Also use FormRequests, not the controller for validation.

Comment: thank you for reply.
For the code, it wasn't accepted by editor, until I've posted it as on line.

Comment: For the solution, I've been mistaken.
It doesn't have to be as the db field name, I only have to name the newpassord-confirmation field for newpassord field to accept it in validation.
thank you